# The moment I add glew.h in my code glut related errors start appearing

Tags: eclipse, opengl, mingw, glut, glew

I am new to C/C++ environment setup. Right now I am using Eclipse IDE. Below are the steps I have followed
After installing MinGW and running basic HelloWorld, C program
1) Copied glew32.dll and glut32.dll to "C:\MinGW\bin"
2) Copied gl.h, glew.h, glu.h and glut.h to "C:\MinGW\include\GL"
3) Copied glew32.lib, glut32.lib and OPENGL32.LIB to "C:\MinGW\lib"
4) In Project->properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->MinGW C Linker->Libraries(-l) added "glew32", "glut32","glu32" and "opengl32"
5) Copied below code

Compiles properly.

The moment I uncomment the first line, ie glew.h, glut related compile errors (added below) appear, Can any one tell me where I am going wrong during setup?

```
//#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void changeViewport(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
}

void render()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);

    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Pinnen is the best");
    glutReshapeFunc(changeViewport);
    glutDisplayFunc(render);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}


Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
undefined reference to `__glutCreateMenuWithExit'   OpenGL      line 549, external location: c:\mingw\include\GL\glut.h C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `__glutCreateWindowWithExit' OpenGL      line 503, external location: c:\mingw\include\GL\glut.h C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `__glutInitWithExit' OpenGL      line 486, external location: c:\mingw\include\GL\glut.h C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `glutDisplayFunc'    OpenGL.c    /OpenGL/src line 25 C/C++ Problem
undefined reference to `glutInitDisplayMode'    OpenGL.c    /OpenGL/src line 21 C/C++ Problem
```

//ignore

Comment: Are you linking with glut and glew? How are you compiling this?

Comment: I am new to C/C++ environment setup. Right now I am using Eclipse IDE. Below are the steps I have followed
After installing MinGW and running basic HelloWorld, C program
1) Copied glew32.dll and glut32.dll to "C:\MinGW\bin"
2) Copied gl.h, glew.h, glu.h and glut.h to "C:\MinGW\include\GL"
3) Copied glew32.lib, glut32.lib and OPENGL32.LIB to "C:\MinGW\lib"
4) In Project->properties->C/C++ Build->Settings->Tool Settings->MinGW C Linker->Libraries(-l) added "glew32", "glut32","glu32" and "opengl32"
5) Copied above code 

After compiling I get compile errors mentioned above.

Comment: You are still unclear in your question. In compiled version of program #include glew.h  is commented or not? If you don't want to use glew, why you are linking it to the compiler? And as I stated in my answer if you want to use glew, delete #include gl.h statement. Btw, glut is very old library I suggest you to use glfw or freeglut instead.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Code compiles fine when I comment the first line and starts showing errors moment I uncomment the first line.

Comment: Thanks a LOT. I am able to compile and run my code with glew.h line uncommented. As you suggested, there seems to be problem with glut.h. No more errors after using freeglut.h. Thank you once again.

Comment: Also, just for future reference, I faced new issue after using glew related functions in my code, at later point in eclipse. (Description Resource Path Location Type undefined reference to `_imp____glewCompileShader' OpenGL.cpp /OpenGL/src line 33 C/C++ Problem). This happens when we link against libraries compiled and meant for visual studio and not for mingw. To fix this, use glew library from http://julianibarz.wordpress.com/2010/05/12/glew-1-5-4-mingw32/. Copy corresponding new glew libs and include files in C:\MinGW\lib and include folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From glew [webpage](http://glew.sourceforge.net/install.html) [delete gl include] :

**Using GLEW as a shared library**

in your program:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
<gl, glu, and glut functionality is available here>
```

or:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
<gl and glu functionality is available here>
```

Remember to link your project with glew32.lib, glu32.lib, and opengl32.lib on Windows and libGLEW.so, libGLU.so, and libGL.so on Unix (-lGLEW -lGLU -lGL).
It is important to keep in mind that glew.h includes neither windows.h nor gl.h. Also, GLEW will warn you by issuing a preprocessor error in case you have included gl.h, glext.h, or glATI.h before glew.h.

Comment: Can you please elaborate based on my new comments in question?